# How to compare to text files using command line tools, under windows

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, find

I have to **sorted** files, say A.md5 and B.md5. I would like to write a small windows batch file, which returns the lines (in my case a list of files), which are present in A but not in B (not case sensitive). I don't need to use arguments; I would like to use it in an actual batch file.

I tried

```
fc A.md5 B.md5
```

but the output is too verbose and there is no way to customise it to behave in a more minimal way. I know it’s possible to do it with find.exe, but I am not yet on a level in find.exe to be able to write this script. BTW, once I've seen a website which had hundreds of find.exe examples explained (I think a similar question was one of them), can you possibly point me to that site?

Comment: Another homework question? How about you put in some effort of your own. Alternatively, if this isn't homework, learnt to use appropriate tools. This is absolutely trivial in Perl, as well as many other languages.

Comment: Why would it be a homework question? I was thinking about comparing a huge list of files to a backup, and doing it by find.exe, but couldn't figure out myself. I think I will stay in the friendlier sites...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cygwin has a collection of unix tools that can be run on windows including "diff" which can produce some very "unverbose" output if used with the correct parameters

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way would be to open a command prompt then type `fc textfile1.txt textfile2.txt > differences.txt` in the location of the files. Alternativly you could add this line in a .bat file.

Comment: The OP says he tried that, but that the output is too verbose.